# What denomination does 穆斯满教依祥派 refer to?

Tags: meaning

I found a Rénmín Rìbào article from May 14th 1950, called 《南疆妇女开始揭下面纱》, which requires login to read. It describes some abusive imam:

> 喀什城内的大地主、穆斯满教依祥派阿訇苏皮禾加，利用他的特权和巫术，压迫和欺骗人民，尤其是百般地蹂躏妇女

From the title 阿訇 and the similarity between “Musulmán” and  穆斯满 it must be a Muslim denomination, but neither did I find Chinese material on 穆斯满, nor on 衣祥派. I read several Rénmín Rìbào articles from the period and all use 伊斯兰。

Comment: I wonder if this was OCR’d wrong. "Ishan" might be the right word for 衣祥派.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a copy of the text [here](http://rmrb.zhouenlai.info/%E4%BA%BA%E6%B0%91%E6%97%A5%E6%8A%A5/1950/05/1950-05-14.htm#0051465):

> ## 南疆妇女开始揭下面纱
>
> 第3版()
>   专栏：
>
> 南疆妇女开始揭下面纱
>
> 今年二月间举行的南疆喀什噶尔（即疏附）市各族各界人民代表会议上，妇女代表们打破了几千年封建传统的桎梏，响亮地喊出第一声：“揭下面纱，婚姻自由”。现在很多妇女都已经揭下了过去不分冬夏都罩着的面纱，当地的封建统治者也已经不敢再骑马扬鞭，对她们实行鞭笞了。
>
> 南疆的妇女，尤其是维吾尔族的妇女，多少年来一直在这一层面纱后过着牢狱一般的生活。她们没有婚姻、人身、教育的自由。在婚姻方面，这里盛行着早婚和多妻的陋习。十二岁的少女，还没有发育健全，便离家成婚。十四、五岁的女子，已是怀抱婴儿的母亲了。老夫少妻的现象也很普遍，许多五、六十岁的老年人，往往与十二岁的幼女成婚。一般富豪和特权者把妇女当作玩具，今日结婚，明日抛弃。
>
> 喀什城内的大地主、穆斯满教依祥派阿訇苏皮禾加，利用他的特权和巫术，压迫和欺骗人民，尤其是百般地蹂躏妇女。喀什中学主任伊不拉英士尔逊说：“苏皮禾加的结婚和离婚，象开玩笑一样。他才三十岁，至少娶了一百五十个老婆。他娶老婆并不花钱，利用他禾加（圣裔）的地位，别人不敢违抗，就得把女子送去。他离了婚的女子，无人再敢娶。”挑水老头子买买提明说：“苏皮禾加娶老婆象喝凉水一样，隔三间二，不是听说他‘抓秧哥’（结婚），就是听说他‘洋度’（离婚）。曾遭苏皮禾加离弃的女子拜儿哥孜汉愤恨地叙述她的遭遇说：“一九四五年，苏皮禾加要娶我。我哥哥说：‘苏皮禾加娶女人如同到马市上骑别人的马一样，既不出钱，又不负责，结果是抛弃。’我也不想嫁。苏皮禾加就叫媒婆则那甫汉转告他的话说：‘我是圣人，她若不嫁我，我念咒把他（指女父）咒死；念穷，叫他发不了财。念的叫她跛了，瞎了，一辈子没有人要她。’我父亲害怕，就许了他。结婚后六个月，有一天他对我说：‘你的期满了，你请假吧，我准你的假，你回去吧。’我向他深深的鞠躬，同时说：‘谢谢禾加。’同他结婚的女子都是：他要娶，不敢不去；他要离，不得不走，还得谢他，不敢向别人说什么话。”
>
> 妇女在婚后的生活更是痛苦和不自由的。奴尔尼沙汉与皮山县乡长艾买提伯克阿吉结婚后，她的丈夫时常将村里的女人招引到家中弹弦作乐，有时还留宿。次日得给他们烧洗澡水，稍有迟慢就是一耳光。还有最野蛮的是所谓“耀把什”，这就是婚前男方提出条件，不准妇女与十二岁以上的男子见面。苏皮禾加每天早起就将他的妻子们锁进黑屋子里，不让她们知道他的家庭里的事，也不让她们和外面的任何男子见面。除此以外，做妻子的还要伺候丈夫吃饭，等丈夫吃完后才能吃他的残汤剩饭。妻子不能跟丈夫并肩在街上走，总要跟在他后面几步。
>
> 妇女既是这样受压迫，因此女子受教育的机会就很少。疏附县共有妇女十二万六千四百五十人，据本年初当地文化教育机关统计，受教育的情况是：中等学校仅有一百三十名女生，小学校也仅有三千九百三十八名女生，其余百分之九十七以上都是文盲。这是号称南疆文化中心的喀什的情形，其他各地情况就可想而知了。
>
> 新疆解放后，广大的妇女同胞们开始走上了光明幸福的道路。新疆省人民政府最近发布的施政方针第四项中明确规定：“妇女与男子享有平等的权利，实行婚姻自由。”在中国共产党领导下，各族各界妇女组织了自己的民主妇女联合会，正为着妇女的权利而奋斗。
>   （新华社）

---

I believe *Ishan* is the equivalent of 衣祥派.

[History of Xinjiang: In the People’s Republic of China (1950s-1980s)](https://pustaqa.com/history-of-xinjiang-in-peoples-republic-of-china-1950-1980/)

> Besides the majority Sunni Muslims in southern Xinjiang, there were various other sects, including Isma’ilis among the Tajiks in Tashkurgan, Shi’ites in Yarkand (Twelve Imam sect descendents of seventeenth-century Punjabi immigrants) and various Sufi orders. These orders were collectively known as *Ishan*, from a Persian word meaning ‘them’ and referring to the orders’ hereditary leaders, believed to be descendents of the orders’ founders and of the Prophet. (Chapter 3 discussed the introduction of these mystical orders into Xinjiang and the secular power achieved by the Naqshbandiyya in particular). Despite the wars and political upheavals from the mid-nineteenth through the mid-twentieth century, many ishan groups remained active during the first half of the twentieth century.

You'd think a guy who'd taken over one hundred and fifty wives by the age of thirty and was a massive landlord would be more well written about, but I can't seem to find much info on him.

Comment: "禾加" should be the equivalent of Hajji (Hadji, Haji, Alhaji, Al hage, Al hag or El-Hajj)